# Speed up a slow Ember Content Filter

Tags: ember.js

I have the following code that filters the content on one of my controllers.  A template loops over a computed property, and displays items.  I then have a text input that filters the content.  Everything works fine, except for when there are a large number of elements, the filtering becomes slow.  I've read a thread elsewhere with an answer from Tom Dale that tried to explain it, but the example was returning a 404.

Where do I go next for trying to speed this up?

Here's the code:

Controller:

```
App.PlaylistIndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    filterString: null,
    filteredSongs: function() {
        var filter = this.get('filterString');
        if(filter == undefined) return this.get('content.songs');
        filter = filter.toLowerCase();
        return this.get('content.songs').filter(function(item, index, enumerable){
            if(item.get('artist').toLowerCase().match(filter.toLowerCase()) || item.get('name').toLowerCase().match(filter.toLowerCase()))
                return item;
        });
    }.property('content.songs', 'filterString')
});
```

Template:

```
{{#each song in controller.filteredSongs}}
  {{song}}{{!-- some song stuff--}}
{{/each}}
```

Filter input:

```
{{input valueBinding='filterString' placeholder='Search for songs within playlist'}}
```

Comment: I'm an Ember noob, but can you do use `@each` in your property? Something like `'content.songs.@each.artist', 'content.songs.@each.name'`? I honestly have no idea if that will even  affect performance though :/

Comment: I think you could... but from my understanding this is an issue with re-rendering the content on every single keystroke.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this :

[JSBIN Using Ember.run.later](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/oXaNOQO/9/)

```
onInputFilterChanged: function(){
      this.set('canProceedFiltering', false);
      Ember.run.later(this, function(){
         this.set('filterString', this.get('inputFilterString'));
         this.set('canProceedFiltering', true);
      },500);
}.observes('inputFilterString')
```

This way, the user can type the text filter and the search will be triggered only after the user has type in a more specific criteria. The downside is the single character searches which will take half a second more..

Comment: I'm OK with a delay in search results being returned, it's just that even in that example there's a notice able lag when typing in a search query (e.g. try typing in 'red1' vs 'red12', then clear the query by pushing backspace)

Comment: then you could use this: draw all the elements in the DOM, and show them asper  the filter : http://emberjs.jsbin.com/oXaNOQO/11/

Comment: I'd probably implement `debounce` into this, it'll make it so the user doesn't feel the delay unless they've stopped typing... http://emberjs.jsbin.com/oXaNOQO/13/edit

Comment: @paulruescher: Can you comment on my answer?

Comment: this looks pretty solid.  I'll try implementing this weekend and will let you know how it works